# Adobe Media Server and TLS 1.2

Tags: apache, ssl, adobe-media-server

I am on AMS 5.07, apache 2.2, and openssl 1.01L and I cannot get TLS 1.2 working. I can only use up to TLS 1.0. Any tricks to getting TLS 1.2 enabled? I'm worried about fully updating apache to 2.4 since it is supposedly configured especially for AMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, unless you upgrade

This issue is fixed with Apache 2.4.3 http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html 
- see SSLCompression Directive

It will only use TLS 1.2 if SSL compression is turned off, and you can't turn it off unless you upgrade.